# Does Spark support BigInteger type?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I know that old versions of Spark support only BigDecimal type from java.math. But I found this pull request: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/10125. I tried to use it and I had no problems using BigInteger type. But in [the spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.package) there is still no mention BigInteger.
So, can I safely use this type?

Comment: BigInteger is 8 bytes numerical value ?

Comment: @BalajiReddy - No.  It is an arbitrary precision integer type; see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: @Stephen got it

Comment: It doesn't. In doubt you call always check [type reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) (nothing changed in 2.4, but its SQL docs are broken for now). There is `bigint` identifier in use, but it simply maps to `long`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spark does support Java BigIntegers but possibly with some loss of precision. If the numerical value of the BigInteger fits in a long (i.e. between -2^63 and 2^63-1) then it will be stored by Spark as a LongType. Otherwise it will be stored as a DecimalType, but this type only supports 38 digits of precision. See [Decimal source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0bfcf9c21069cabafc6fff47a801aa86ca13c608/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/Decimal.scala#L144) for details.